# .NET 8 Blazor Web App with individual accounts auto logout accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

I created new project using .NET 8 Blazor Web App with individual accounts template but login with `isPersistent` does not work correctly and requires user login again after about a hour.
It use default method to login users:

```cs
public async Task LoginUser()
{
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
        RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
    }
    //remaining logics
}
```

But even with `Input.RememberMe = true` website require me to login again after about a hour.

I also trid use alter method:

```cs
//user is ApplicationUser from database
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
```

It login successfully but also require login again after about an hour.

I checked identity cookie and it expires only after two weeks.

[image: site cookies]

A bit compact version of screenshot:
[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to  increase the [SecurityStampValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.securitystampvalidatoroptions.validationinterval?view=aspnetcore-8.0) interval to a safely long value like :

```
builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => 
                   o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
```

And you can try to increase the [IdleTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.sessionoptions.idletimeout?view=aspnetcore-8.0) :

```
 options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
```

Have a look at [ISecurityStampValidator and SignOut everywhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#isecuritystampvalidator-and-signout-everywhere) and [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to know more.